# Create Items from 3 collections using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've 3 collections with exactly the same items count.

I need to create a new collection based on these 3 collections item values.

Exemple :

```
List<double> list1;
List<double> list2;
List<double> list3;

List<Item> list4;

public class Item
{
   public double Value1{get;set;}
   public double Value2{get;set;}
   public double Value3{get;set;}
}
```

I try to achieve this using Linq.

I tried :

```
    var query = from pt in list1
                from at in list2
                from ct in list3
                select new Item
                           {
                               Value1 = pt,
                               Value2 = at,
                               Value3 = ct
                           };
```

But i got a OutOfMemoryException, my 3 lists are huge.

Any help ?

Comment: Wait - when did you get an OutOfMemoryException? The query you showed **doesn't actually execute anything**. The new items will be created as you foreach over them. That shouldn't cause an OutOfMemory unless you're keeping each item in memory.

Comment: @Judah, i get an OutOfMemoryException after calling .ToList()

Comment: Yeah, because then you're creating all the items in memory. Can you avoid calling .ToList()? Even better, can list1, list2 and list3 be of type IEnumerable<T>, rather than list? If you use deferred execution, you won't keep all the items in memory, and thus you won't hit an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: The reason you run out of memory is because you are doing a cartesian product of three lists, rather than treating them as parallel arrays. That means you are getting the results of a triple nested-loop rather than the results of one loop using the same index for all three lists. Python has a `zip` function that takes any number of collections and returns a collection of tuples. LINQ's Zip function tries (and fails) to do the same, because it only allows two sequences at a time and requires a transform function. Works ok for two lists, but 3+ is a nightmare.

Comment: Good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14639590/116891

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple Lists into one List with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639481/merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-with-linq)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're talking about `List<T>` (which has a fast indexer), and you provide the guarantee that all three lists are of the same length, the easiest way would be:

```
var items = from index in Enumerable.Range(0, list1.Count)
            select new Item
            {
                Value1 = list1[index],
                Value2 = list2[index],
                Value3 = list3[index]
            };
```

This approach obviously won't work well with collections that don't support fast indexers. A more general approach would be to write a `Zip3` method, such as the one that comes with the F# `Collections.Seq` module: [**`Seq.zip3<'T1,'T2,'T3>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370585.aspx). Otherwise, you could chain two [**`Enumerable.Zip`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) calls together to produce similar behaviour (as mentioned in other answers), although this does look quite ugly.

Comment: It was a useful answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could [**zip**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) them together - this is zipping up first list2 and list3, then zips the combined list together with list1:

```
list4 = list1.Zip(list2.Zip(list3, (b, c) => new { b, c }),
                  (a, b) => new Item { Value1 = a, Value2 = b.b, Value3 = b.c })
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The concept of [mapping sequences or lists into the arguments of functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) originated in the LISP programming language, a bit over 50 years ago. In LISP it is trivial because of its untyped and list-oriented nature. But, doing it in a strongly-typed language is difficult, at least in terms of solving the general problem of mapping *n* sequences to a function that takes *n* arguments.

Here's a feeble stab at what should accommodate most needs:

```
// Methods that work like LISP's (mapcar) when used with
// more than 1 list argument (2 to 4 included here, add
// versions for more arguments as needed).
//
// The methods will only yield as many results as there
// are elements in the argument sequence that yields the
// fewest elements, in cases where argument sequences do
// not all yield the same number of elements (which is
// the same behavior as their LISP counterpart).
//
// An interesting twist, is that we make these methods
// extension methods of the invoked function, because it
// doesn't seem natural to make one of the sequences of
// arguments the target.
//
// Nonetheless, they can still be called as non-extension
// methods through the declaring type:
//
// (Untested):
//
//   string[] fruit = new string[]
//      {"apples", "oranges", "pears", "banannas"};
//
//   double[] prices = new double[] {1.25, 1.50, 1.00, 0.75};
//
//   int[] amounts = new int[] {12, 8, 24, 5};
//
//
//   Func<int, string, double, string> func =
//     ( amount, name, price ) => string.Format(
//        "{{0} lbs. of {1} @ ${2:F2} / lb. = ${3:F2}",
//         amount, name, price, amount * price );
//
//   var invoice = func.Map( amounts, fruit, prices );
//
//   foreach( string item in invoice )
//      Console.WriteLine( item );
//
// It's also worth noting that CLR 3.5 introduces the
// "Zip" extension method, that allows mapping of two
// sequences to a function taking two arguments, but
// without some wild contortion involving currying and
// multiple calls to Zip, it can't solve the general
// problem (mapping n sequences to a function taking
// that many arguments).


public static class Sequence
{
  // Map elements of 2 sequences to the arguments of
  // a function taking 2 args, and return results:

  public static IEnumerable<T> Map<A1, A2, T>(
    this Func<A1, A2, T> func,
    IEnumerable<A1> a1,
    IEnumerable<A2> a2 )
  {
    using( IEnumerator<A1> e1 = a1.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A2> e2 = a2.GetEnumerator() )
    {
      IEnumerator[] args = new IEnumerator[] {e1, e2};
      while( args.TrueForAll( e => e.MoveNext() ) )
      {
        yield return func( e1.Current, e2.Current );
      }
    }
  }

  // 3 arguments

  public static IEnumerable<T> Map<A1, A2, A3, T>( this
    this Func<A1, A2, A3, T> func,
    IEnumerable<A1> a1,
    IEnumerable<A2> a2,
    IEnumerable<A3> a3 )
  {
    using( IEnumerator<A1> e1 = a1.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A2> e2 = a2.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A3> e3 = a3.GetEnumerator() )
    {
      IEnumerator[] args = new IEnumerator[] {e1, e2, e3};
      while( args.TrueForAll( e => e.MoveNext() ) )
      {
        yield return func( e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current );
      }
    }
  }

  // 4 arguments

  public static IEnumerable<T> Map<A1, A2, A3, A4, T>(
    this Func<A1, A2, A3, A4, T> func,
    IEnumerable<A1> a1,
    IEnumerable<A2> a2,
    IEnumerable<A3> a3,
    IEnumerable<A4> a4 )
  {
    using( IEnumerator<A1> e1 = a1.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A2> e2 = a2.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A3> e3 = a3.GetEnumerator() )
    using( IEnumerator<A4> e4 = a4.GetEnumerator() )
    {
      IEnumerator[] args = new IEnumerator[] {e1, e2, e3, e4};
      while( args.TrueForAll( e => e.MoveNext() ) )
      {
        yield return func( e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current, e4.Current );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simplified version which takes **any** number of sequences (as an array) of the same type and zips them together:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T>[] sequences, Func<T[], TResult> resultSelector)
{
    var enumerators = sequences.Select(s => s.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    while(enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
        yield return resultSelector(enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray());
}
```

### Pros

- any number of sequences
- four lines of code
- another overload for LINQ `.Zip()` method
- zips all sequences at once instead of chaining `.Zip` to add one more sequence each time

### Cons

- same type required for all sequences (not a problem in many situations)
- no checking for same list length (add a line if you need it)

### Usage

[image: Zipping colors]

Answer (score 2):

a little shabby but this should work.

```
  List<Item> list4 =
            list1.Select((l1i, i) => new Item {Value1 = l1i, Value2 = list2[i], Value3 = list3[i]}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following:

```
 var combined = list1.Select((x, i) => new Item {Value1 = x, Value2 = list2.ElementAt(i), list3 = range3.ElementAt(i)});
```

If you're always going to be performing this on lists, you can place `.ElementAt(i)` with the `[i]` indexer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all the lists are of equal size you should use a for-loop:

```
        List<Item> combinedList = new List<Item>(list1.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            combinedList.Add(new Item()
            {
                Value1 = list1[i],
                Value2 = list2[i],
                Value3 = list3[i]
            });
        }
```

This solution is very simple and easy to understand, no LINQ required.

Comment: But unlike link, this is not lazily-loaded; all items are added in one pass. Given that he's already experiencing out of memory exceptions, this will make the problem worse.