# 3 IEnumerables into 1 tuple

Tags: c#, tuples, ienumerable

I've got 3 IEnumerables of integers and I would like to make an array of Tuple out of it. What's the best approach? If I had just 2 IEnumerables I would use Zip but in this case?

Comment: See duplicate. `var result = i1.Concat(i2).Concat(i3);`. If this doesn't answer your question, show a small code example of what you currently have and explain what you'd like to accomplish.

Comment: That's not the same problem

Comment: @CodeCaster I think he wants the result to be of type `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>>`

Comment: @Matthew that's exactly what I want

Comment: Since answers are closed: take a look at the Zip method and you can easily adjust it for 3 enumerables http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @darenn If the previous comment describes your problem than name your question like: Combining items into tuples from multiple(>2) IEnumerables in parallel by one. It is an awful title, but I am unable to think of any better one.

Comment: In that case see [How to combine more than two generic lists in C# Zip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip).

Comment: But what about the arbitrary number of IEnumerables? Zipping the zipped multiple times is not the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a scenario where it is easiest to use the iterator directly, rather than `foreach`:

```
using(var i1 = seq1.GetEnumerator())
using(var i2 = seq2.GetEnumerator())
using(var i3 = seq3.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(i1.MoveNext() && i2.MoveNext() && i3.MoveNext())
    {
        var tuple = Tuple.Create(i1.Current, i2.Current, i3.Current);
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `// ...` here could be:

- `yield return tuple`
- `someList.Add(tuple);`
- or the actual thing you want to do

Answer (score 4):

It is possible (though maybe not the best performant solution) to `Zip` twice, as in:

```
var result = seq1.Zip(seq2, Tuple.Create)
    .Zip(seq3, (t2, z) => Tuple.Create(t2.Item1, t2.Item2, z));
```