# Join two lists without having any matching columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have two separate lists from db as :

`List<Id> lstId` which has values `0,1,2,…`

`List<name> lstnaname` which has values `“a”,”b”,c”`

I want to combine these two lists which don’t have any common column .
My expected output would be

```
List<output> out 
Out[0] = {0,”a”}
Out[1] = {1,”b”}
```

I tried using concat in linq but it just add the listA to listB.

Join clause doesn’t work because there are no common fields.
How would I achieve it?

Comment: Why would you expect `{0, "a"}` rather than `{1, "a"}` for example? Are you just relying on the ordering?

Comment: Yes, its just one-to-one ordering 0th element of listA to 0th element of listB and so on....

Comment: Please check this link for the help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Zip`:

```
var result = lstId.Zip(lstName, (id, name) => new { id, name });
```