# How to get first index in list of list

Tags: c#

How can I get the first indexes from my list of lists and get it's average value. Currently I have return value on my list:

```
[["1.11, 2.11, 3.11"], ["2.11, 3.11, 4.11"], ["4.11, 5.11, 6.11"]]
```

Here is my expected result:

```
var index0 = 2.44
var index1 = 3.44
var index2 = 4.44
```

On single list only I am using this to get the average:

```
var avg = myList.Select(double.Parse).Average();
```

Any suggestion/comments TIA.

Comment: Isn't `index2` supposed to be 4.44? 13.33 is the sum of the second index values, not the average.

Comment: Is this a List or 2D array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to get `avg` based on columns index instead of rows then `.Zip` will be one option for you,

Suppose your list of list of string is,

```
var myList = new List<List<string>>
{
       new List<string> { "1.11, 2.11, 3.11" },  //<= Notice here single item in list with comma(,) separated
       new List<string> { "2.11, 3.11, 4.11" },
       new List<string> { "4.11, 5.11, 6.11" }
};
```

So you need to first split your string in inner list with comma(`,`) to get each item as separate string,

```
var list = myList
    .SelectMany(x => x
           .Select(y => y.Split(',')
           .Select(z => z.Trim())
           .ToList()))
    .ToList();
```

Then you can make `.Zip` on all above 3 list by

```
var results = list[0]
    .Zip(list[1], (a, b) => double.Parse(a) + double.Parse(b))
    .Zip(list[2], (x, y) => (x + double.Parse(y)) / 3)
    .ToList();

//------------------Print the result---------------

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(item, 2));
}
```

**How `.Zip` works?**

Lets take all columns value on index 0.

```
a = "1.11"
b = "2.11"
```

Then 1st `Zip` result will be =>

```
double.Parse(a) + double.Parse(b) 
= 1.11 + 2.11 
= 3.22
```

So for 2nd `.Zip` the `x` now be the result of the above 1st `.Zip` that means

```
x = 3.22
y = "4.11"
```

Then 2nd `Zip` result will be =>

```
(x + double.Parse(y)) / 3 
= (3.22 + 4.11) / 3 
= 2.44
```

So for `Average` of your values at column index 0 => **`2.44`**

**In above,**

- *list[0]* : 1st list in your list of list of string.
- *list[1]* : 2nd list in your list of list of string.
- *list[2]* : 3rd list in your list of list of string.

**Output:** (From Console)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit Solution because you edited.

```
                String[][] TValue = new String[][]
                {
                    new String[] {"1.11", "2.11", "3.11" },
                    new String[] {"2.11", "3.11", "4.11" }, 
                    new String[] {"4.11", "5.11", "6.11" }
                };

                Console.WriteLine("Avg[0] => {0:F2}", TValue.Select(x => double.Parse(x[0])).Average());
                Console.WriteLine("Avg[1] => {0:F2}", TValue.Select(x => double.Parse(x[1])).Average());
                Console.WriteLine("Avg[2] => {0:F2}", TValue.Select(x => double.Parse(x[2])).Average());
```

this is what you expected.

hope this work.

Comment: I updated my question sorry my list value has string values and needed to parse it into double

Comment: use parse on x => x[0]

Comment: @Rockn'Roll Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do so using Linq.

**Updated based on comment**

```
var list = new [] {  "1.11, 2.11, 3.11" , "2.11,3.11, 4.11" ,  "4.11,5.11,6.11" };
var collection = list.Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(c => double.Parse(c)).ToList()).ToList();
var result = collection.First()
               .Select((dummy, i) =>
                  collection.Average(inner => inner[i]));
```

### Output

```
2.44
3.44
4.44
```

Comment: I updated my question sorry my list value has string values and needed to parse it into double

Comment: I am having error on var 'c' cannot convert char to string

Comment: as expected values, it seems average of every columns. not rows.

Comment: my bad I am having this result on my list: [["1.11, 2.11, 3.11"], ["2.11, 3.11, 4.11"], ["4.11, 5.11, 6.11"]]

Comment: I think need to split it then get the average

Answer (score 0):

You can zip all three lists

using zipThree from [How to combine more than two generic lists in C# Zip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class MyFunkyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipThree<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T1> source,
        IEnumerable<T2> second,
        IEnumerable<T3> third,
        Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> func)
    {
        using (var e1 = source.GetEnumerator())
        using (var e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        using (var e3 = third.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext() && e3.MoveNext())
                yield return func(e1.Current, e2.Current, e3.Current);
        }
    }
}

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var list = new List<List<double>> { new List<double> {1.11,2.11,3.11},  new List<double>  {2.11,3.11,4.11},  new List<double>  {4.11,5.11,6.11} };

    var a = list[0].ZipThree(list[1], list[2], (x, y, z) => (x + y + z) / 3);
    Console.WriteLine(
      string.Join(",",
      a.Select(s => s.ToString())));
  }
}
```

And it returns

```
2.44333, 3.443333, 4.44333
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all the inner lists have the same length, and you want to count the average of the corresponding indices (i.e. index0 is average of 0th value from each list, index1 is average of the 1st value etc.).

In such case to obtain the averages for each index you use the following code:

```
int listLength = myList.First().Length; // Length for an array
                                        // Count for a List<T>

var averages = Enumerable.Range(0, listLength).Select(
    index => myList.Average(innerList => double.Parse(innerList[index]))
    ).ToList();
```