# Convert multiple IEnumerable to IEnumerable of Tuple

Tags: c#, linq

I am using ZIP to create a tuple of 3 lists as:

```
var result = l1
  .Zip(l2)
  .Zip(l3);
```

But then each item I get is something like:

```
((l11, l21), l31)
```

How to use Zip to create IEnumerable of Tuples from N lists where each item would become:

```
(l11, l21, l31, l41, ...)
```

Comment: You'd have to do something like `l1.Zip(l2).Zip(l3, (x, y) => (x.Item1, x.Item2, y)).Zip(l4, (x, y) => (x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3, y))` and so on.  I don't think there's a simple way to turn a n tuple into a n+1 tuple.

Comment: I think [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip) might help you.