# How to concat multiple list of object in single column c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing an issue while displaying multiple lists the value in a single row column.

Here is an example of code.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<object>> keyvalues = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
        keyvalues.Add("Code", new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        keyvalues.Add("Name", new List<object>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" });
        keyvalues.Add("Age", new List<object>() { 20, 30, 40, 50 });        

        var listData = keyvalues.Select(x => x.Value).Select((x, i) => new { obj = x, index = i });
        var listData = keyvalues.Select((x, iparent) => x.Value.Select((z, i) => new { value = string.Concat(z, x.Value[i]) }).ToList()).ToList();
                
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> Expected output

```
1A20
2B30
3C40
4D50
```

Comment: I'm not sure where columns come into this, but it seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297124/how-to-combine-more-than-two-generic-lists-in-c-sharp-zip) might answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, While posting the question I'm looking the same but not able to solve the problem let me check again :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily use `Zip` here. However, you could roll your own

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoStuff<T, T2>(Dictionary<T, List<T2>> source)
{
   var max = source.Values.Max(x => x?.Count ?? 0);
   for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
      yield return string.Concat(source.Values.Select(x => x.ElementAtOrDefault(i)));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = DoStuff(keyvalues);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,results));
```

**Output**

```
1A20
2B30
3C40
4D50
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DoStuff<T>(List<T>[] source)
{
   var max = source.Max(x => x?.Count ?? 0);
   for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
      yield return string.Concat(source.Select(x => x.ElementAtOrDefault(i)));
}

...

var results = DoStuff(keyvalues.Values.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,results));
```

Comment: Showing same values

Comment: @jishansiddique Try again, i had a mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 6, you could make use of the new 3 way Zip extension.

```
var result = keyvalues["Code"].Zip(keyvalues["Name"], keyvalues["Age"])
            .Select(x=> $"{x.First}{x.Second}{x.Third}");
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine but I've made one example in the real problem `key name` not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it so complicated?

```
for(int x = 0; x<keyValues["Code"].Count; x++)
  Console.WriteLine(
    keyValues["Code"][x]+
    keyValues["Name"][x]+
    keyValues["Age"][x]
  );
```

LINQ's a hammer; not every problem is a nail.

<sub>ps if you have N keys, you can easily turn it into a</sub>

```
var keys = new[]{"Code","Name","Age","Foo","Bar"};
for(...)
  foreach(var k in keys)
    ... //some concat here or use the values directly eg adding to your page
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine but I've made one example in the real problem key name not fixed.

Comment: That is what the "if you have N keys" part at the bottom of the answer is for.. Those can come from anywhere, not just hard coded.. but if you want specific help you need to put it in your question; we can only respond to the problem we see