# How to use Zip on three IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Items from 3 collections using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284315/create-items-from-3-collections-using-linq)

I have performed a zippage of two sequences as follows.

```
IEnumerable<Wazoo> zipped = arr1.Zip(arr2, (outer, inner) =>
  new Wazoo{P1 = outer, P2 = inner});
```

Now, I just realized that I'll be using three sequences, not two. So I tried to redesign the code to something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Wazoo> zipped = arr1.Zip(arr2, arr3, (e1, e2, e3) =>
  new Wazoo{P1 = e1, P2 = e2, P3 = e3});
```

Of course, it didn't work. Is there a way to deploy `Zip` to incorporate what I'm aiming for? Is there an other method for such usage? Will I have to zip two of the sequences and then zip them with the third unzipping them in the process?

At this point I'm about to create a simple `for`-loop and `yield return` the requested structure. Should I? I'm on .Net 4.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284315/create-items-from-3-collections-using-linq

Comment: @AakashM: I think that's not just similar, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Ben so I see, this one is about arrays which have a fast indexer like the `List`s in the link, so yes the same solution applies. There remains unasked the interesting question about what to do with an arbitrary `IEnumerable<>`...

Comment: @AakashM That's pretty well covered in the answers to the other question also.

Comment: @AakashM Yes, it is. I didn't find it before posting. You're absolutely correct. Should I remove the question or ask a mod to close it?

Comment: Only a duplicate if the other question claims to `perform zippage` as well.

Comment: The other question isn't an exact duplicate.  It specifies lists, and most of the answers rely on that.  This is asking for zipping 3 sequences, which can't use the indexer.  Now, that said, some of the answers to the other question do work for this case, but that doesn't change the fact that the questions are still different so they are not "exact duplicate" questions.

Comment: @Servy this question clearly says (in the body, not the title) that it's about **arrays** not arbitrary sequences

Comment: @AakashM And yet the title says otherwise

Comment: @Servy it does? :p Anyway, now we have a good answer for when someone does actually want to zip three sequences!

Comment: @AakashM Well, it's possible he was just using arrays as test cases and that he really does need to zip three `IEnumerable`s.

Comment: @Servy Spot on. My case is as you said. You have a good sense of the intentions behind. Of course, I should have been more clear on my question. In my head an array is anything that is not "single". Note that I didn't write `Array` but just array. Does one get reputation if a suggested closure gets approved?

Comment: @Chamster I have edited the question based on that comment.  Yes, you get reputation when a question is closed, as long as it is not deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could either use two calls to the existing `Zip` (it would be a bit messy, but it would work) or you could just make your own `Zip` that takes 3 sequences.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult>
    (this IEnumerable<TFirst> source, IEnumerable<TSecond> second
    , IEnumerable<TThird> third
    , Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TResult> selector)
{
    using(IEnumerator<TFirst> iterator1 = source.GetEnumerator())
    using(IEnumerator<TSecond> iterator2 = second.GetEnumerator())
    using (IEnumerator<TThird> iterator3 = third.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (iterator1.MoveNext() && iterator2.MoveNext()
            && iterator3.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return selector(iterator1.Current, iterator2.Current,
                iterator3.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except I would rename the method to `PerformZippage`