# How to map to add multiple IEnumerable<int> to an IEnumerable<int> property of a model

Tags: c#, .net, linq, automapper

Let's say I have this code

```
int? pk=100;
int? ptype1 =51;
int? ptype2 =52;
int? ptype3 =53;

public class SampleDto
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Property1{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Property2{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Property3{ get; set; }
}

SampleDto sample = new SampleDto();
sample.Property1.Add(11);
sample.Property1.Add(12);
sample.Property1.Add(13);
sample.Property2.Add(21);
sample.Property2.Add(22);
sample.Property2.Add(23);
sample.Property3.Add(31);
sample.Property3.Add(32);
sample.Property3.Add(33);
```

How do I map SampleDto properties to add to an IEnumerable of SampleModel using Automapper

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; } //same for all pk 
    public int? TypeId { get; set; } //ptype depending on the property. Ex. ptype1 for Property1
    public int? Values { get; set; } //Value of Property
}
```

With the values above, I want an expected result of IEnumerable of SampleModel with the following data:

```
Id =100, TypeId =51, Values =11
Id =100, TypeId =51, Values =12
Id =100, TypeId =51, Values =13
Id =100, TypeId =52, Values =21
Id =100, TypeId =52, Values =22
Id =100, TypeId =52, Values =23
Id =100, TypeId =53, Values =31
Id =100, TypeId =53, Values =32
Id =100, TypeId =53, Values =33
```

Comment: Feels like you're asking Automapper to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640881/how-to-use-zip-on-three-ienumerables or from the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284315/create-items-from-3-collections-using-linq ?

Comment: But the more I read your question, the less I understand what you're trying to do. Please give example data as-is and also desired results. You can use JSON representation

Comment: @CaiusJard ok. editting now

Comment: Added expected result

Comment: So you want automapper to do `sample.Property1.Select(p1=>new{p=p1,pt=ptype1}) .Concat(sample.Property2.Select(p2=>new{p=p2,pt=ptype2})) .Concat(sample.Property3.Select(p3=>new{p=p3,pt=ptype3})) .Select(new SampleModel{Id=pk,TypeId=ptype,Values=p})` ?

Comment: WE kind of want to do it in automapper

Comment: @ByronScott that's not what Automapper is about. There's no mapping involved in this case, you're concatenating sequences, not mapping objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, there's always the final select that could be mapped :)

Comment: So, did Automapper saved you time? Based on the question did not ;). Write code to concat collections by hand - written only once, ti will work and you spend much less time then asking question about Automapper ;)

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper is the wrong tool for the job, since you are not doing a one-to-one mapping (there is no common 'root' between SampleDto and SampleModel).

Using LINQ, you can however create a rather straightforward transformation function that transforms a list of `SampleModel` objects to the corresponding list of `SampleDto` objects. Something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<SampleDto> ConvertFunction(IEnumerable<SampleModel> sample)
{
    var query = from d in sample
                group d by d.Id into g
                let lookup = g.ToLookup(x => x.TypeId, x => x.Values)
                select new SampleDto
                {
                    Property1 = lookup[51],
                    Property2 = lookup[52],
                    Property3 = lookup[53]
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Then if you absolutely must, you could integrate this in automapper with a custom conversion function:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<SampleModel>, IEnumerable<SampleDto>>()
        .ConvertUsing(input => ConvertFunction(input))
    );
```

This allows you to do this:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
var result = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SampleDto>>(sample);
```