# How to project from several sequences using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

All

I have three collections:

```
{"Alex", "Anna"}
{19, 20}
{"A", "B"}
```

I want to project them all into one sequence of objects of type "Student" using LINQ and the following lambda or something:

```
(name, age, grade)=>new Student(name, age, grade)
```

Result should be two Student objects ("Alex", 19, "A") and ("Anna", 20, "B")

How can I do this?

Comment: How those sequences are defined? I mean their `Type`? Your question is unclear.

Comment: So far you have provided a requirement but no question. I'm going to assume the question is "how do I do this?".

Comment: C# doesn't have sequences. Are you trying to convert F# code to C#? LINQ allows Zip-ing two enumerables but three is a different case

Comment: They are three simple enumerables, arrays or lists

Comment: Wait. Why do you have list of three sequences in first place if you need them to be together? Why not have a single sequence `List<Student>` from the beginning itself?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel notice the F#-like syntax. The sequences may come from various sources. Combining them in F# is easy. Elegantly doing the same in C# is non-trivial

Comment: If those sequences implement `IList<T>` use a `for-loop`. That's simple and the most efficient approach.

Comment: @DanielKelley the answers show that the question isn't trivial,even though the wording could be better. Converting an elegant F# statement to C# isn't easy and the answers show that. For example, how can you remove the double iteration inherent in the double-Zip solution? This isn't nitpicking - such statements are very common in data-processing scenarios with languages like F# and R. An elegant and *efficient* solution in C# is very useful

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not one word of that comment addresses my comment. "Questions" with interesting problems don't by definition become immune from downvotes if they are asked poorly and show no effort by the asker. Hence downvotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge multiple Lists into one List with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639481/merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-with-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two `Zip` to achieve this:

```
names.Zip(ages, (n,a) => new { name = n, age = a })
     .Zip(grades, (s,g) => new Student { Name = s.name, Age = s.age, Grade = g });
```

Comment: I think your anonymous class makes for a more readable solution then my tuple.

Comment: The double-zip solution iterates twice over the first two sequences. For data-processing scenarios this is undesirable. I'll try to write a three-way Zip but I wonder if there are libraries out there that do this already.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, there is only one iteration. The first lambda and the second lambda are continually interleaved. See this dotnetfiddle for an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cRDQWM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it seems it [has been done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14639590/238902)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `Zip`

```
var names = new[] {"Alex", "Anna"};
var ages = new[] {19, 20}
var grades = new[] {"A", "B"}


var students = names.Zip(ages, (n, a) => Tuple.Create(n, a))
                    .Zip(grades, (t, g) => new Student(t.Item1, t.Item2, g));
```

Comment: I like the tuple, this is one of the rare cases where it's useful.

Comment: The double-zip solution iterates twice over the first two sequences. For data-processing scenarios this is undesirable. I'll try to write a three-way Zip but I wonder if there are libraries out there that do this already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - See my response to your same comment on Selman's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27920582/25216

Comment: So obvious in retrospective! The results are enumerables so the lambdas are always lazily evaluated. Enumerable never ceases to amaze me

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I got to use tuples again in another question. I find that their real power is that they override`Equals` and `GetHashCode` in a useful way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953160/linq-select-distinct-set-and-retrive-different-column/27953448#27953448

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: not a real advantage over their competitors anonymous types because they also provide that. The only advantage of tuples are that they can be processed in a different method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - OK, I just wrote more test code, and I see what you mean. I hadn't realised that anonymous types also override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: interesting is that the order matters, you can read about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/01/30/anonymous-types-unify-within-an-assembly-part-two.aspx