# How to join a list of lists in a unique list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `List` of objects that have a `List` of `long`. I need to get all `long` of all objects and join it to a unique list. 
How to do this using `System.Linq`?

This is my code actually (with this code I get a `List` of `List` of `long`)

```
var result = LIST1.Select(x => x.LIST2.Select(y => y.Id).ToList()).Tolist();
```

Comment: `SelectMany` is what you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge multiple Lists into one List with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639481/merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-with-linq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This flattens your list and then does a distinct on it

```
LIST1.SelectMany(a => a.LIST2.Select(b => b.Id)).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use selectMany instead of Select

```
var result = LIST1.SelectMany(x => x.LIST2.Select(y => y.Id)).Tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dont get it if you need to join the lists of objects or you need to union all, but for join you could use:

```
var result = (from Item1 in LIST1
             join Item2 in LIST2
             on Item1.Id equals Item2.Id
             select new { Item1, Item2 }).ToList();
```