# Transpose member arrays into collection of objects with corresponding singular members using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, automapper, transpose

I have the following classes:

```
class Foo
{
    public int X[];
    public int Y[];
    public int Z[];
}

class Bar
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}
```

I wish to create the following AutoMapper map:

```
CreateMap<Foo, IEnumerable<Bar>>
```

This is to map a single `Foo` object to a collection of `Bar` such that `Foo.X[i]` and `Foo.Y[i]` will map to `Bar[i].X` and `Bar[i].Y`. The arrays will always be the same length. Is this possible with AutoMapper using built-in functionality? Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to explicitly map each member programmatically.

As an added bonus, I would also like to support postfixes on the source using `RecognizePostfixes("Postfix")` and the following version of `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
    public int XPostfix[];
    public int YPostfix[];
    public int ZPostfix[];
}
```

Comment: Write it with LINQ and then, if there is repetition, add AM.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you post how this would be done as an answer as I couldn't see how to achieve it with LINQ without explicitly specifying the source member arrays? I'm working on a `ITypeConverter` solution at present using reflection, but I feel AutoMapper should still be part of it somewhere, especially because of the last part of the question that I just added regarding postfixes. I basically want to map in any way necessary while still taking advantage of any AutoMapper config in the `ResolutionContext`.

Comment: The `Zip` LINQ operator helps here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu `Zip` isn't helpful in my case as my use case has an arbitrary number of properties. There's a convoluted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519048/197591) which uses `Zip` together with `Aggregate` to somehow achieve this, but it really abuses `Aggregate` and uses a random source member array for deciding its initial seed size. The other answers using a custom overloaded extension method of `Zip` seem more appropriate, and I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847859/197591) to this effect. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [pointer in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58826848/transpose-member-arrays-into-collection-of-objects-with-corresponding-singular-m#comment103947237_58826848) from @LucianBargaoanu together with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38271036/197591) on another question, I was able to come up with a solution using a `ITypeConverter` and an `IEnumerable` extension method.

This is the `ITypeConverter`:

```
class TransposeConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<TSource, IEnumerable<TDestination>> where TDestination : class, new()
{
    public IEnumerable<TDestination> Convert(TSource source, IEnumerable<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Zip all the member collections from the source object together into a single collection then map to the destination based on the property names.
        return typeof(TSource).GetProperties()
            .Select(p => ((IEnumerable)p.GetValue(source)).Cast<object>().Select(item => (item, p.Name)))
            .Zip(s => context.Mapper.Map<TDestination>(s.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, e => e.item)));
    }
}
```

This is the `Zip` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> collections, Func<IEnumerable<T>, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    var enumerators = collections.Select(s => s.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
    {
        yield return resultSelector(enumerators.Select(e => e.Current));
    }
}
```

However, this only solves the first part of the question. It doesn't resolve the "added bonus" part where I wish to handle postfixes on the property names. I've raised [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58847135/197591) for this.