# How to add custom configuration such as RecognizePostfixes to AutoMapper for mapping from Dictionary<string, object> or ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, dictionary, configuration, automapper, expandoobject

I am using AutoMapper to map a `Dictionary<string, object>` to a class `Bar` where the source keys have postfixes which I configure in AutoMapper using `RecognizePostfixes`:

```
var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.RecognizePostfixes("Postfix");
}));

var foo = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"XPostfix", 1}, {"YPostfix", 2}};
var bar = mapper.Map<Bar>(foo);
```

`Bar` is defined as:

```
class Bar
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Unfortunately, the properties are not mapped unless the source keys and destination property names match. It seems that `RecognizePostfixes` doesn't work when mapping from `Dictionary<string, object>`. I also tried using `ExpandoObject`. AutoMapper supports both as per [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html), but seemingly without configuration support.

Is it possible to achieve this in some way using AutoMapper? My only restriction is that I must be able to dynamically configure the source properties, hence why I can use `Dictionary<string, object>` or `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: You need to add another step, a typed map that will consider the configuration.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I tried adding `cfg.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, object>, Bar>();` to the config, but this doesn't fix it. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No. You map from dictionary to an intermediary class. And then you map from that class to your final destination. This last step will use your configuration.

Comment: Thanks - this worked, but it seems a little overkill. I've raised an [issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1151).

Comment: We have no plans to implement that.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That's why I created the issue.

Comment: Note also that I created the issue under the wrong project. This is the correct one: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3262