# How to put two different List of tables into one new List c#

Tags: c#

I have two lists, one list type is int and the other type is string.

```
     List<int> IntList = new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5};
     List<string> StringList = new List<string>(){"a","b","c","d","e"};
```

I want to combine these two lists to a new list.
And I create a new class called Table

```
    public class Table
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i combine IntList  and StringList  to `list<Table>`

Like this output

```
    List<Table>
    {a=1,b=a}
    {a=2,b=b}
    {a=3,b=c}
    {a=4,b=d}
    {a=5,b=e}
```

---

Edite
if i want to add the third list

```
list<int>{0,0,0,0,0}

 public class Table
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

output

```
   List<Table>
   {a=1,b=a,c=0}
   {a=2,b=b,c=0}
   {a=3,b=c,c=0}
   {a=4,b=d,c=0}
   {a=5,b=e,c=0}
```

---

Edite again

Under the URL of this funtion is vey useful ，it can combine multiple list in to one list

Title :Merge multiple Lists into one List with LINQ

[Merge multiple Lists into one List with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639481/merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-with-linq)

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, this looks like C# code.

Comment: Why did you change the tag back to `C` after I changed it to `C#`? This is not `C` code.

Comment: Instead of creating 2 lists like this, you should create a map, then put each entry of this map into the Table list.

Comment: var combined = IntList.Concat(StringList);  requires Using System.Linq;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `System.Linq` extension method [`Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) to return a `Table` object for each pair of corresponding elements from the two sequences:

```
List<Table> result = IntList?.Zip(StringList, (i, s) => new Table {a = i, b = s}).ToList();
```

Comment: If i will add the third list，how can i use it??

Comment: `var result = ThirdList?.Zip(IntList?.Zip(StringList, (i, s) => new {i, s}), (t, l) => new Table {a = l.i, b = l.s, c = t}).ToList();` Assuming that `Table` has a property `c` that is of the same type as the members of `ThirdList`. This basically takes the code from the answer except returns an anonymous type with the first zipped items, and then zips that with the third list item and creates a `Table` from the values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use the List Index to join them,
so you can use `LINQ Join` and `List.IndexOf` to do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> IntList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        List<string> StringList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

        var expected = (from t1 in IntList
                        join t2 in StringList on IntList.IndexOf(t1) equals StringList.IndexOf(t2)
                        select new Table { a = t1, b = t2 }
        ).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(expected);
    }
}

public class Table
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[Online Demo Link | C# Online Compiler | .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SxhtB0)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Linq `Select()`

```
//If IntList and StringList are of same size
var result = IntList.Select((x, i) => new Table(){a = x, b = StringList[i]});
```

If length is not equal, then you can add `if..else` loop,

```
List<Table> result = new List<Table>();
if(IntList.Count() > StringList.Count())
    result = StringList.Select((x, i) => new Table(){a = IntList[i], b = x}).ToList();
else
    result = IntList.Select((x, i) => new Table(){a = x, b = StringList[i]}).ToList();
```

[Online Demo: .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EUM3C1)

Answer (score 1):

The Linq [`Zip` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) can do this.

```
IntList.Zip(StringList, (i, s) => new Table { a = i, b = s });
```